# Getting form inputs with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```
<form id="file-upload">
  <input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Title">
  <input type="text" name="alt[]" placeholder="Alt">
  <input type="text" name="keywords[]" placeholder="Keywords">

  <input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Title">
  <input type="text" name="alt[]" placeholder="Alt">
  <input type="text" name="keywords[]" placeholder="Keywords">
  //etc
</form>
```

My form has many fields with the same name.

I wish to run through the form in JS, getting the title, keywords and alt values and appending them to my form data object, I will then add my image to the formData object and save the image plus its meta data server side.

My issue regards getting the form input values. Is it best to seralize the form or perhaps just loop through the dom elements? How can I do this?

So I need to:

1. Get first title, alt, keywords field - how?
2. Append to formData, and file and send to server - I can do this bit.
3. Get second title, alt, keywords field - how?
4. Append to formData, and file and send to server - I can do this bit.

and so on...

Comment: Try yourself first, then ask about *specific* problems you encounter.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByName("title[]");` returns an array of all matching elements. Then get the first, second, etc by index.

```
document.getElementsByName("title[]")[0];    // first title
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName

In jQuery, this works fine:

```
var firstTitle = $("[name='title[]']")[0].value;
```

although you should definitely cache the selector:

```
var titles = $("[name='title[]']");
var firstTitle = titles[0].value;
var secondTitle = titles[1].value;
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I do this in jquery and get the value. I've tried: $('[name="title[]"]')[0].val() but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and created this fiddle. Hope it helps.

```
var values = $("input[name='title\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

$("<div>title[0]:"+values[0]+"</div>").appendTo('#results');
$("<div>title[1]:"+values[1]+"</div>").appendTo('#results');
$("<div>title[2]:"+values[2]+"</div>").appendTo('#results');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y5n8A/

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Try to use (map) function, this is the best way to make an array

Comment: Try adding a code example, maybe directly helping their problem?